# Having trouble with Rails query, ambiguous column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So I'm having a little difficulty using Rails to query some data.

I have two models and I'm attempting to join one on to the other. My issue arises using a group by method. Both models have the same attribute name and this is causing an ambiguous column name error. My query is:

`Photo.joins(:votes).group(:photo_id, :image, :title, :bytes, :user_id, :public_id).order("count_all desc").limit(10).count`

How can I choose which model that the group by attributes use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the table name like this:

```
Photo.joins(:votes)
     .group(:photo_id, :image, :title, :bytes, 'photos.user_id', :public_id)
     .order("count_all desc")
     .limit(10)
     .count
```

Assuming `user_id` is the ambiguous column name and `photos` is the actual tablename.

Comment: Awesome, works great, I thought it would be "Photo.user_id" but what you have makes sense now.